# Question about Monte Carlo Integration

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am a self-learner of measure and probability theory. This problem is from the textbook of Durret 4th edition.  The whole question is as below:

**Monte Carlo Integration**. Let $f$ be a measurable function on [0,1] with $\int _{0}^{1}|f(x)|<\infty$, let $U_1, U_2,\dots$ be independent and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and let $I_n=n^{-1}\big(f(U_1)+\dots+f(U_2)\big)$:
show that 
$$
I_n \rightarrow I=\int_0^1 f dx$$ 
in probability.

It seems that I can use WLLN to show it.

**My question is**: how to show that
$$
E(f(U))=\int_{0}^1 f dx\:?
$$

Many thanks!

Comment: It is already assumed that $\int_0^1|f(x)|<\infty$, why are you needing to show it again?

Comment: Is not (2) the definition of expectation?  (Assuming $U$ is the interval $[0,1]$)

Comment: I have already made some chang. Many thanks!